# C: Comparing lower and upper-case ASCII elements

Tags: c, function, for-loop, scanf

[image: My task is to simulate a vote.]

Hi, beginner here. My code's function `count_vote()` is erraneous, and I have exhausted myself trying to figure out what I've done wrong. My plan of attack was to shift the case of my input 'vote' character, and then equate the integer value associated with its ASCII character with the first letter of a candidate. If there was a match, I would incremement a vote count variable associated to that candidate.

I am having trouble reading in single characters as ASCII values, and I get strange behaviour when attempting to print these values in my `count_vote()` for loop; each letter inputted is interpretted as having the same integer value.

Please offer some advice with how I can fix my janky code. Thank-you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Library to easily change an input character to its lower-case variant
#include <ctype.h>
// Library to handle comparison of strings
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_BUFFER 20
#define NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES 3

// Define with type identifiers
void vote_count(int number_of_voters, char * candidate_1, char * candidate_2, char * candidate_3);

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_voters;
    printf("Number of Voters: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_voters);

    char candidate_1[NAME_BUFFER], candidate_2[NAME_BUFFER], candidate_3[NAME_BUFFER];
    
    printf("Name of 1st Candidate: ");
    scanf("%s", candidate_1);
    
    printf("Name of 2nd Candidate: ");
    scanf("%s", candidate_2);
    
    printf("Name of 3rd Candidate: ");
    scanf("%s", candidate_3);

    // Pass without type identifiers
    vote_count(number_of_voters, candidate_1, candidate_2, candidate_3);

    return 0;
}

// Re-define with type identifiers
void vote_count(int number_of_voters, char * candidate_1, char * candidate_2, char * candidate_3)
{
    int candidate_1_prefix_letter = candidate_1[0];
    int candidate_2_prefix_letter = candidate_2[0];
    int candidate_3_prefix_letter = candidate_3[0];

    int candidate_1_votes = 0, candidate_2_votes = 0, candidate_3_votes = 0;
    
    // Declare a variable for the vote choice
    int vote_choice;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < number_of_voters; counter++)
    {   

        scanf("%d", &vote_choice);        
        // Use this when colleting only one character at a time
        getchar();
        

        // Check who was voted for
        if (toupper(vote_choice) == candidate_1_prefix_letter)
        {
            candidate_1_votes++;
        }
        else if (toupper(vote_choice) == candidate_2_prefix_letter)
        {
            candidate_2_votes++;
        }
        else if (toupper(vote_choice) == candidate_3_prefix_letter)
        {
            candidate_3_votes++;
        }
        
    }

    // Print the votes
    printf("%s: %d\n" , candidate_1, candidate_1_votes);
    printf("%s: %d\n" , candidate_2, candidate_2_votes);
    printf("%s: %d\n" , candidate_3, candidate_3_votes);


    // Check who won
    if (((candidate_1_votes == candidate_2_votes) && (candidate_1_votes != 0)) || ((candidate_1_votes == candidate_3_votes) && (candidate_1_votes != 0)) || ((candidate_2_votes == candidate_3_votes) && (candidate_3_votes != 0)))
    {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
    else if ((candidate_1_votes > candidate_2_votes) && (candidate_1_votes > candidate_3_votes))
    {
        printf("%s has won the vote! Praise %s!\n", candidate_1, candidate_1);
    }
    else if ((candidate_2_votes > candidate_1_votes) && (candidate_2_votes > candidate_3_votes))
    {
        printf("%s has won the vote! Praise %s!\n", candidate_2, candidate_2);
    }
    else if ((candidate_3_votes > candidate_1_votes) && (candidate_3_votes > candidate_2_votes))
    {
        printf("%s has won the vote! Praise %s!\n", candidate_3, candidate_3);
    }

}
```

When attempting to print single character values from my `count_vote`'s for loop, each character input is interpretted as having the same integer value.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, there is unfortunately no standard C function for case-insensitive comparison (but POSIX have `strcasecmp`, Windows and MSVC have `stricmp`). It's however quite simple to create such a function yourself, simply loop over both strings until one reaches the null-terminator, get a character from each of the string, and use e.g. `tolower` on the characters before comparing them.

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “I get strange behaviour … each letter inputted is interpretted as having the same integer value.” Always post a [mre] with debugging questions. That includes an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d", &vote_choice);` does not read a character as ASCII. It looks for a decimal numeral in the input, like `347` or `-92`, converts it to an `int`, and stores that in `vote_choice`.

To read a single character, use `char vote_choice;` and `scanf(" %c", &vote_choice);`. The space before `%c` tells `scanf` to read and discard white-space characters in the stream until it finds a non-white-space character.